# PHP Empty and data validation

Tags: php, validation

When a user submit forms,i'm checking empty validation and data validation.

For ex:In data ,first field is name,i'll check whether user has entered any other characters else than alpha character's.if he has entered then will show him an error message.Name should contain minimum of 4 characters and max of 20 characters

I'm using this code but it is not working correctly.How to check the regex.

```
$validate = array("Category"=>"$productCategory", "Name" => "$productName");

$error = '';

foreach ($validate as $key => $field) {

    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{4,20}$/i', $$field)) {
       echo $error .= $field;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide input, output, expected output.

Comment: Are accented characters, or other Unicode characters, allowed in names?

Comment: plus you have `$$field` instead of `$field`

Comment: I find this line `echo $error .= $field;` pretty strange. Can anyone explain it's logic?

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius : none, we all missed it :) Updated my answer to show a correct way to use $error in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the preg_match, you type `$$field` (2x$) instead of `$field`, your regex is fine it will match:

```
 - a character between a - z (case insensitive)
or
 - a digit between 0 - 9
or 
 - a "space" character.
```

Update code to answer @Andrius Naruševičius comment

```
$validate = array("Category" => $productCategory, "Name" => $productName);
$error = '';
foreach ($validate as $key => $field)
{
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{4,20}$/i',$field))
    {
       $error.= $field;
    }
}

if($error)
{
    echo $error;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: :a valid name can have spaces a-z,A-z & 0-9.

Comment: :Where to add error messages.Say,i've 10 regex and 10 feild,how do i use this in this logic.When form submitted,if 5 error all should be showed to user.

Comment: @user1415759 Removed \w and added a-z in the regex (\w allows a what you need + the underscore character). Second, it will print all 5 errors and exit the code, you don't whant to continue execution after an error occured ...

Comment: :I wrote an update,check you check my code.How do i validate empty field.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
$validate = array("Category"=>$productCategory, "Name" => $productName);

foreach ($validate as $key => $field) {

    if (preg_match('/^[\w\d]{4,20}$/i',$field)) {
       echo $error .= $field;
    }
}
```